# C# - Ternary operator between Dictionary and Object[]

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, object

How i can implement a ternary operator between a Dictionary type and a array of objects in C#?

I tried bellow, but gives me error:

`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>" and "object[]`

```
    public async Task NovoEmail(Escrita.Email email)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await $"{_configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Url"]}/users/{email.Remetente}/sendMail"
                            .WithOAuthBearerToken(await _graph.Token())
                            .PostJsonAsync(new
                            {
                                message = new
                                {
                                    subject = email.Assunto,
                                    body = new { contentType = "HTML", content = email.Corpo },
                                    toRecipients = email.Destinatarios.Select(destinatario => new { emailAddress = new { address = destinatario } }),
                                    ccRecipients = email.Copias.Select(copia => new { emailAddress = new { address = copia } }),
                                    attachments = email.Anexos.Count > 0 ? email.Anexos.Select(anexo => new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                        { "@odata.type", "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment" },
                                        { "name", anexo.FileName },
                                        { "contentType", anexo.ContentType },
                                        { "contentBytes", _base64.FormFileToBase64(anexo) }
                                     }) : new object[] { }
                                }
                            });

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if you use `new Dictionary<string, string>()` ? (or `null`)

Comment: instead of this `new object[]` use `new Dictionary<string, string>()`

Comment: I think your code will throw run time exception that `An item with the same key has already been added.` if there are multiple `Anexos`

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty: No, because it's creating a *sequence* of dictionaries.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just tested a similar example, I got to know the output result, Thanks

Comment: Why do you even test for `>0`? `email.Anexos.Select(...)` will return an empty enumeration if there are no items. If you do need it, then it's `Enumerable.Empty<Dictionary<string,string>>()` that you need to match the `Select`.

Comment: if the Anexos are never null you do not need the condition > 0 just do the select statement, at the end you becomming the same result

Comment: @IanMercer Agreed, this doesn't seem needed. If someone where to insist though, I'd reach for `Enumerable.Empty<IDictionary<string,string>>()` though as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the ternary operator for the zero elements condition: without it you get an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>>()`:

```
email.Anexos.Select(anexo => new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                    { "@odata.type", "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment" },
                                    { "name", anexo.FileName },
                                    { "contentType", anexo.ContentType },
                                    { "contentBytes", _base64.FormFileToBase64(anexo) }
                                 })
```

If you need an array simply call `.ToArray()` on that. If it has no elements in the enumeration you get a zero length array.

If for some other reason you really did need a ternary operator then the empty equivalent for your `Select` expression would be:

```
Enumerable.Empty<Dictionary<string,string>>()
```